# How to extract highest value from multiple values in a cell?

Tags: pandas, bash

I have a column containing multiple values in same cell. I want to get highest single value from the cell and put a new column

```
Values
9.912e-05,4.956e-05
9.878e-05,2.47e-05
9.861e-05,7.396e-05
9.854e-05,0.0002463
9.853e-05,4.927e-05
9.852e-05,7.389e-05
9.845e-05,7.384e-05,4.923e-05,9.845e-05,0.0002707
10
25
```

Expected output

```
Values                 Highest
9.912e-05,4.956e-05    9.912e-05
9.878e-05,2.47e-05     9.878e-05
9.861e-05,7.396e-05    9.861e-05
9.854e-05,0.0002463    0.0002463
9.853e-05,4.927e-05    9.853e-05
9.852e-05,7.389e-05    9.852e-05
9.845e-05,7.384e-05,4.923e-05,9.845e-05,0.0002707    9.845e-05
10                     10
25                     25
```

Can we do it via bash or pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do `str.split` with `max`

```
s=df.Values.str.split(',',expand=True).astype(float).max(1)
0    0.000099
1    0.000099
2    0.000099
3    0.000246
4    0.000099
5    0.000099
6    0.000271
dtype: float64
df['High']=s
```